# Expression for setting lowest n bits that works even when n equals word size

Tags: perl

NB: the purpose of this question is to understand Perl's bitwise operators better.  I know of ways to compute the number *U* described below.

Let `$i` be a nonnegative integer.  I'm looking for a simple expression `E<$i>`<sup>1</sup> that will evaluate to the *unsigned int* *U*, whose `$i` lowest bits are all 1's, and whose remaining bits are all 0's.  E.g. `E<8>` should be 255.  In particular, if `$i` equals the machine's word size (*W*), `E<$i>` should equal `~0`<sup>2</sup>.

The expressions `(1 << $i) - 1` and `~(~0 << $i)` both do the right thing, except when `$i` equals *W*, in which case they both take on the value `0`, rather than `~0`.

I'm looking for a way to do this that does not require computing *W* first.

---

EDIT: OK, I thought of an ugly, plodding solution

```
$i < 1 ? 0 : do { my $j = 1 << $i - 1; $j < $j << 1 ? ( $j << 1 ) - 1 : ~0 }
```

or

```
$i < 1 ? 0 : ( 1 << ( $i - 1 ) ) < ( 1 << $i ) ? ( 1 << $i ) - 1 : ~0
```

(Also impractical, of course.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I'm using the strange notation `E<$i>` as shorthand for "expression based on `$i`".</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I don't have a strong preference at the moment for what `E<$i>` should evaluate to when `$i` is strictly *greater* than *W*.</sup>

Comment: "the purpose of this question is to understand Perl's bitwise operators better." If you really want to understand them, you should look at how they're implemented: see `pp_left_shift` in [pp.c](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/maint-5.22/pp.c#L1918). `pp_left_shift` simply uses C's left shift operator; in C, it's undefined behavior to shift a value by the number of bits it contains, which is why I think `(1 << $i) - 1` and `~(~0 << $i)` fail.

Comment: `E<$i>` is a strange notation for `f($i)`

Comment: @ikegami: that's because my intention was *precisely to avoid* functional notation, since that would have *invariably* been misinterpreted as my asking for a `sub`, whereas I was asking for an expression.  Of course, `E<$i>` *is* a function of `$i`, in the more general/mathematical sense of the term, but if I had used `E($i)`, most, if not all, the answers I would have gotten would have been of the form `sub E { ... }`, ant that's *not* what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On systems where `eval($Config{nv_overflows_integers_at}) >= 2**($Config{ptrsize*8})` (which excludes one that uses double-precision floats and 64-bit ints),

```
2**$i - 1
```

On all systems,

```
( int(2**$i) - 1 )|0
```

- When i<W, `int` will convert the NV into an IV/UV, allowing the subtraction to work on systems with the precision of NVs is less than the size of UVs. `|0` has no effect in this case.
- When i≥W, `int` has no effect, so the subtraction has no effect. `|0` therefore overflows, in which case Perl returns the largest integer.

**I don't know how reliable that `|0` behaviour is. It could be compiler-specific. Don't use this!**

Answer (score 2):

```
use Config qw( %Config );

$i >= $Config{uvsize}*8 ? ~0 : ~(~0 << $i)
```

Technically, the word size is looked up, not computed.

Answer (score 1):

Fun challenge!

```
use Devel::Peek qw[Dump];

for my $n (8, 16, 32, 64) {
  Dump(~(((1 << ($n - 1)) << 1) - 1) ^ ~0);
}
```

Output:

```
SV = IV(0x7ff60b835508) at 0x7ff60b835518
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 255
SV = IV(0x7ff60b835508) at 0x7ff60b835518
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 65535
SV = IV(0x7ff60b835508) at 0x7ff60b835518
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 4294967295
SV = IV(0x7ff60b835508) at 0x7ff60b835518
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,IOK,pIOK,IsUV)
  UV = 18446744073709551615
```

Perl compiled with:

```
ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8
```

Comment: Nice.  It fails for `$n = 0`, but that's an easy exception to check for.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Thanks for the edit, they where indeed redundant!

Comment: @kjo, how much data can you store if you have zero bits?

Comment: `$n` does not refer to the number of bits available for storage, but to the number of the bits (in the word's low end) that are 1.  When `$n = 0`, then *U* is obviously 0.  IOW, the problem is perfectly well defined for the case `$n = 0`.  (In the problem statement, I referred to it as a "non-negative integer".)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the shift operators in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Shift-Operators) has an answer to your problem: `use bigint;`.

From the documentation:

> Note that both `<<` and `>>` in Perl are implemented directly using `<<` and `>>` in C. If `use integer` (see [Integer Arithmetic](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Integer-Arithmetic)) is in force then signed C integers are used, else unsigned C integers are used. Either way, the implementation isn't going to generate results larger than the size of the integer type Perl was built with (32 bits or 64 bits).
>
> The result of overflowing the range of the integers is undefined because it is undefined also in C. In other words, using 32-bit integers, `1 << 32` is undefined. Shifting by a negative number of bits is also undefined.
>
> If you get tired of being subject to your platform's native integers, the `use bigint` pragma neatly sidesteps the issue altogether:
>
> ```
> print 20 << 20;  # 20971520
> print 20 << 40;  # 5120 on 32-bit machines, 
>                  # 21990232555520 on 64-bit machines
> use bigint;
> print 20 << 100; # 25353012004564588029934064107520
> ```

Comment: Overflowing a unsigned integer in C has a defined behavior, it simply "wraps around". Perl has traditionally always used (and still uses) unsigned integers when using bitwise op's unless the integer pragma is in effect.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, IMHO you should remove some of the unnecessary documentation you added in your edit, the first paragraph excluding the last sentence with a pointer to perldoc  would be enough.